# Digital certify login web application

Tags: authentication, certificate

There are some way to implementing login in my WebApplication MVC with digital certificate x590?

Using PKIjs (https://pkijs.org/) or another way is possible list all digital certificate stored in client side?

tks

Luciano Castro

Answer (score 0):

Author of [PKI.js](https://pkijs.org/) here.
It is not possible with PKI.js or any other pure JavaScript solution to read certs in the local certificate store.

PKIjs and Forge provide for the browser sandbox to implement [X.509](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509) related concepts, but does not allow you to escape the browser same-origin security policy.